# Can't have + V3 or Couldn't have + V3

Tags: modal-verbs, could-modal, can-modal

Is there any difference between the following sentences?

> If Jones was at work until six, he can't have done the murder.
>
> If Jones was at work until six, he couldn't have done the murder.

Comment: The first might be said by a detective in the course of an investigation. The second might be part of a story, describing the detective's reasoning in the past tense.

Comment: Why are people silently downvoting this question?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I Dved. I DVed simply that considering the rep amount the OP has, I wondered why she/he couldn't have distinguished such (probably) easy 2 sentences. Sorry for having not said prior to DV.

Comment: @Kentaro: You seriously think this is an *easy* question? I think it's a tricky issue even for native speakers!

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica The second sentence is outright past tense. If you don't like my "judge", your "retaliation" is very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

> 1: *If Jones was at work until six, **he can't have** done the murder.*
> ***it is not possible*** (now) that he did it (then)
> 2: *If Jones was at work until six, **he couldn't have** done the murder.*
> ***it was not possible*** (then) for him to *do / have done* it (then)

Where in practice both assertions can only actually *mean* the same thing. If he ***couldn't have done the murder*** at the time the murder was committed, it remains true forever into the future that he ***can not have done it***.

Which tense to use is a stylistic choice in contexts like this - it depends on whether you want to focus attention on the *current* situation (he IS innocent), or on what happened in the past (he DIDN'T do it).

---

EDIT
I found [this](https://commonenglisherrors.com/cant-have-been-couldnt-have-been/#:%7E:text=in%20their%20usages%3F-,While%20Can%27t%20Have%20(Been)%20is%20used%20to%20refer,way%20back%20in%20the%20past.&text=He%27s%20been%20limping%20since%20this,the%20race%20yesterday%20at%20all.) in *commonenglisherrors.com*...

> *While **Can’t Have (Been)** is used to refer to an incident in the near past, **Couldn’t Have (Been)** is used for an event that happened way back in the past.*

...which arguably is simply another way of describing the "attention focus" point I made above - since ***can't*** focuses on the Present, and ***couldn't*** focuses on the Past, it's perfectly natural to see the latter as more appropriate when that "Past" is *a long way away from* the "Present" (it's in the more *distant* past).

Comment: To make it clear, it is correct to say "cannot have v3" is past form of the ability, while  " could have v3" is past form of the possibility from grammar perspective.

Comment: But "can" is also used for "possibility" in  the negative form in the present such as  " it can't be true."

Comment: I don't understand the point you're making. But I have come across a claim that there *can be* a difference, so I'll edit that in.

Comment: ...but I can say that your "ability / possibility" distinction is ***not*** relevant here.